# Not able to scroll the list of process to chose from Profiler tool in Android Studio 3.2

Tags: android, android-studio, profiler

I have updated the latest **Android Studio 3.2**, after that, I am not able to choose the desired process from the list in the Profiler tool.

**Not able to scroll** the  **the list of all process** from the updated **Profiler Tool** in Android Studio 3.2

Kindly suggest, if there is any other way to see it.

Comment: Have you gone through the documentation on [Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)?

Comment: @SanthoshJoseph : It is nothing to do with the documentation. It is a UI issue with the latest Studio it seems, I am not able to scroll the list in profiler tool